# Can I recover my seed words?

Tags: multibit

I am using MultiBit Ver. 0.5.14, I have my wallet open in it, but do not know my seed words, I had them saved most likely on my computer or printed out on paper, but after 3 moves, 2 computer crashes and 1 computer replacement I have no idea where they might be or what they are, can I recover them, if so, how?

Thank You

Michael Grace

Comment: Worst case, just create a new wallet whose seed words you do know and move all your funds to it.

Comment: I went to make a new wallet in MultiBit Ver. 0.5.14, it makes one without asking for seed words, it only wanted a password, so maybe I do not need to worry about them as I could not even remember making them but thought I must have since 2 other places I just made wallets for asked for them.

Answer (score 3):

Multibit 0.5.14 is a MultiBit classic version which does not have seed words and does not support Hierarchical Deterministic wallets. So long as you know the password to your wallet and you have an up to date backup of it, you will be able to access your Bitcoin. There are no seed words for you to recover.

However, MultiBit 0.5.14 is an extremely old version of MultiBit. It is a version of MultiBit classic which was deprecated and replaced with MultiBit HD (which has seed words). Furthermore, MultiBit HD is no longer maintained and supported. So your version of MultiBit is several years out of date, contains potential vulnerabilities, and is no longer maintained whatsoever. I would highly advise that you switch to using a different wallet software such as Electrum.